# Message Queue Listener and RESTful integration

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, websphere-8

My project publishes RESTful/SOAP services. One of these sends messages to a JMS queue on a Websphere application server. The application runs on the same application server. What I need is to define a listener to this queue. How can I activate this listener without a direct call from the service?

The project structure looks like this:

```
Project:
  -ejb
  -rest
  -soap
```

The user calls methods on the service, which calls the EJB component, so I dont have any main method where I can init the listener.

I need a solution which activates a permanent listener to the queue.

I already have the source code I just don't know how to initialize the listener.

Comment: What JMS queue are you using and how is it configured on Websphere? How is your project configured? With Spring, CDI, other?

Comment: It doesnt matter... all the function works very well. Import is to define one area in my ejb wich init something by startup

Comment: Hint: the EJB should probably not be responsible for starting up the listener. It should be configured within your application context somewhere as a standalone component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSphere MDB with a lot of configuration it works!!!! But look at this:

```
    @MessageDriven(activationConfig={
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination",     propertyValue="myDestination"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class MsgBean implements javax.jms.MessageListener {

  public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message msg) {

      String receivedMsg = ((TextMessage) msg).getText();
      System.out.println("Received message: " + receivedMsg);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you have the issues:

Do something like:

- define the JMS resources in WebSphere
- inject the javax.jms.Queue as a Resource (or maybe using CDI? Not sure if CDI supports this) in a EJB
- use this Queue to send messages
- define a MDB (@MessageDriven) to listen for messages

Comment: Thx. My first try was to do with ejb Annotations like @Startup and Postconst.... And call there my Recv method with while(1).

But WebSphere isnt supported this way. It has to go with MDB...